# Osmdroid: show and hide markers description on click

Tags: java, focus, hide, overlay, osmdroid

I am programming an app in Java using Android Studio.
I already displayed a map using osmdroid, added some overlays to display markers on special locations and added a title & a description to the markers.

Now I display the title & description of the marker on click using the setFocusItemsOnTap method.
My problem is that I am not able to hide the title & description of the marker on a second click (so if its already shown). Is there any way to do this?

Or if thats not possible is there a way to only display the title & description of one marker at once using the setFocusItemsOnTab methode?

```
public static List<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

//[...]

items.add(new OverlayItem("uid1","Title", "Description", new GeoPoint(51.398,6.875)));

//[...]

List<OverlayItem> currentList;
currentList = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        currentList.add(items.get(i));

//[...]

final ItemizedOverlayWithFocus<OverlayItem> mOverlay = new ItemizedOverlayWithFocus<OverlayItem>(this, currentList, new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {
                    //here it should decide if the title & description is already shown or not. (true => hide it, false => display it)
                    return true;
                }
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongPress(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {
                    return false;
                }
        });

mOverlay.setFocusItemsOnTap(true);
```

I have to use these parts of the code, because i wanted to add different markers and i wanted to be able to focus all of them. Also i need to be able to add them to a dynamic list during runtime.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you're sticking with ItemizedIconOverlay, I believe you can only have one popup at a time. You would have to subclass ItemizedIconOverlay and override the draw method to support rendering popups for multiple items at a time.

I think you'll have better luck with the Marker class. It already supports the click to close function. Again, only a single marker popup can be displayed at a time. This can be overridden by supplying your own InfoWindow instances for each marker.

Comment: Thanks i solved it using ItemizedIconOverlay instead of ItemizedOverlayWithFocus and using the osmbonuspack